# run whenever gem in mongrel development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want run [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and I have this task in **schedule.rb** file:

```
every 5.minutes do 
 rake "directory:cleanup"
end
```

I'm in environment development with Mongrel.

**Why this task is not fired every 5 minutes?**

**What am I doing wrong?**

PD: *The task works fine from console.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the `whenever --update-crontab` command from the root directory of your application. This will add the task to your crontab.

However, if you're using OSX, there probably isn't a crontab to begin with so this won't work.

If you are constantly needing to cleanup some directories in development, I think there might be a better solution. Look into using something like [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) perhaps.